# Applescript: Condense multiple lines into one in TextWrangler

Tags: applescript

I am trying to make an Applescript that condenses multiple lines down to one line.

For example

```
"a
b
c
d"
```

to

```
('a','b','c','d')
```

The string is in TextWrangler, and my script is

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {return & linefeed, return, linefeed, character id 8233, character id 8232}

tell application "TextWrangler"
    tell text window 1
        set i to 2
        set selection to "('
"
        repeat while i < 6
            select (insertion point before line i)
            select line the (startLine of the selection)
            copy (contents of the selection) as text to myText
            set newText to text items of myText
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
            set newText to newText as text
            select insertion point after line 1

            if i = 2 then
                set selection to newText
            else
                set selection to "','" & newText
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat

        set selection to "')"
    end tell
end tell
```

The issue is that result of the script is ('a','b','b'), so I am unable to remove 'new line' character. If someone help me to improve it to work with dynamic number of lines, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text from TextWrangler, you would use:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set myString to text of window 1
end tell
```

To update the text in TextWrangler, you use:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set text of window 1 to myString
end tell
```

So, you can wrap those two pieces of code around [adayzdone's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249684/2348587).

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set myString to text of window 1
end tell

set myList to paragraphs of myString

set listCount to count myList
repeat with i from 1 to my listCount
    set item i of myList to quoted form of item i of myList
end repeat

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ", "}
set newString to ("(" & myList as text) & ")"
set text item delimiters to TID

tell application "TextWrangler"
    set text of window 1 to myString
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
set myString to "a
b
c
d"

set myList to paragraphs of myString

set listCount to count myList
repeat with i from 1 to my listCount
    set item i of myList to quoted form of item i of myList
end repeat

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ", "}
set newString to ("(" & myList as text) & ")"
set text item delimiters to TID

return newString
```